# Read dynamic key from registry

Tags: windows, vbscript, scripting, registry

I need to read a dynamic registry key from Windows. Then I need to dump the name of the key to XML.

```
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' AMADEUS
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
StrKeyPath = "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Amadeus\1aAutoUpdate\Config\Cache\Certificates"
key_name = "Amadeus"
key_edition = ""
key_release = ""
subKey = ""
oReg.GetStringValue HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,strKeyPath,subKey,key_text,
if IsNull(key_text) then
    ' do nothing
else
    result.WriteText "      <key>" & vbcrlf
    result.WriteText "          <key_name>" & escape_xml(key_name) & "</key_name>" & vbcrlf
    result.WriteText "          <key_text>" & escape_xml(key_text) & "</key_text>" & vbcrlf
    result.WriteText "          <key_release>" & escape_xml(key_release) & "</key_release>" & vbcrlf
    result.WriteText "          <key_edition>" & escape_xml(key_edition) & "</key_edition>" & vbcrlf
    result.WriteText "      </key>" & vbcrlf
    key_text = ""
    key_release = ""
    key_edition = ""
end if
```

Image with the keyword / dynamic key:

[image: http://subefotos.com/ver/?3278958fa1864db5d2612ee3be8f1136o.jpg]

Comment: What do you mean by "dynamic"? That the subkey (not folder) below the `Certificates` key can have an arbitrary name? Also, you didn't describe the problem you're facing. Are you unable to enumerate the subkey? Do you get an error? You need to give us something to work with.

Comment: Exacto no puedo obtener la subclave ya que el nombre de la carpeta cambia por lo tanto no lo puedo ingresar en el codigo!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to enumerate the subkeys of `[HKLM\SOFTWARE\...\Certificates]` you need to use the [`EnumKey`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa390387%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method. Also, with the WMI registry methods you *must* specify the hive as a numeric constant. Including it in the path does not work.

Try this:

```
Const HKLM = &H80000002

key = "SOFTWARE\Amadeus\1aAutoUpdate\Config\Cache\Certificates"

Set reg = GetObject("winmgmts://./root/default:StdRegProv")

rc = reg.EnumKey(HKLM, key, subKeys)
For Each sk In subKeys
  WScript.Echo sk
Next
```